# Receiving mails with incomplete body

Tags: postfix, sendmail, outlook

I have a smart host with Getmail+Sendmail+Postfix+Dovecot connected with a remote server. This smart host only works for one domain. Postfix is used to send mails within this domain and for outside domains. To receive I use Getmail to receive mail through POP3S from my remote server and then forwarding with Sendmail to my local user accounts.

To receive mail automatically from outside domains, I have set a script to run 5 in 5 minutes (with crontab), to check all remote email accounts at my remote server, to get new mail through Getmail.

Now, I have received some strange behaviours from one user, who is sending mail from an outside domain, to the domain of my smarthost. Sometimes, the destination only receives part of the mail that have been sended, it seems like this server sometimes dont get all the data of mail, and the only related thing that I can see is that there are text formatation that maybe are triggering this, but is not a specific type.

In mail.log and getmail logs, there is no issue being reported, all seems fine.

This user is using Outlook.

Anyone here have saw this before?

**Note: If you need any config from this server, I can provide.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debug, I notice that this was being done in Getmail.

And with the help of **Charles Cazabon** from **Getmail**, I was able to solve this "mistery".

It seems that there was some missing some extra arguments in each getmail RC that  I have generated, when evoking sendmail, like:

> -f [sender]:
>                 Set  the  envelope  sender  address.  This  is the address where
>                 delivery problems are sent to. With Postfix versions before 2.1,
>                 the   Errors-To:  message  header  overrides  the  error  return
>                 address.

and the argument that was causing some users to only receive half of theirs mails:

> -i:     When reading a message from standard input, don't treat  a 
>   line
>                 with only a . character as the end of input.

Now this is the default getmail RC that I am using in this smart host:

```
[retriever]
type = SimplePOP3SSLRetriever
server = [remote server FQDN]
port: 995
username = test@[remote server domain]
password = qwe123

[destination]
type = MDA_external
path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
arguments = ('-i','-f [local network admin user]',"-bm", "test")
unixfrom = true

[options]
delete = true
message_log = ~/.getmail/logs/getmailrc_test.log
```

I hope this could help others having the same problem.

**A BIG thanks for the help Charles Cazabon!!!**